# TinyMCE editor replacing tags inside Joomla articles

Tags: editor, seo, joomla, tinymce

I have a front page of my site optimized for SEO.
I am using  tags to mark important content.
When I edit my article in admin section with TinyMCE editor, it replaces
 tags with  tags, which I want to avoid.

Any ideas how to make 
this web editor (TinyMCE) not replace my `<strong>` tags?

Comment: What, exactly, does "replaces tags with tags" mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: When I insert strong tag in html mode and switch to design mode, the strong tag get replaces with bold tag, which I can see next time I go into html mode of the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While valid_elements should effect strong tag, in practice in doesn't.
The solution is to comment out the following code in tiny_mce.js -

```
/*h=h.replace(/<strong([^>]*)>/gi,'<b$1>');h=h.replace(/<\/strong>/gi,'</b>');*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your tinyMCE.init() call and look for the valid_elements option.  If it's set to something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    valid_elements : "..., b/strong, ..."
});
```

That means it's set to replace strong tags with b tags.  Just switch to allowing both ("b, strong", or even replacing b tags with strong tags like

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    valid_elements : "..., strong/b, ..."
});
```

[See also this page in the documentation.](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements)